# NgGrid with MVC cellFilter doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, datetime, filter, ng-grid

I am working with MVC and AngularJs. The problem is that my model (class) has property of type DateTime. When I get JSON from database, it converts data to

```
/Date(1432617857710)/
```

["Solution"](http://www.victorshi.com/blog/post/How-to-format-a-datetime-column-in-ng-grid) that is posted here should help, but it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my gridOptions:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'testData',
        enableRowSelection: false,
        columnDefs: [
            { width: 50, cellTemplate: '<div ng-show=checkForNullId(row.entity.Id) class="icon_animated" style="height:50px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></div>' },
            { field: 'Id', visible: false },
            { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name' },
            { field: 'Age', displayName: 'Age' },
            { field: 'Date', displayName: 'Register Date', cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd"' },
            { width: 50, cellTemplate: '<button ng-hide=checkForNullId(row.entity.Id) id="editBtn" type="button" title="Redaguoti" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" ng-click="edit(row.entity)" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button> ' },
            { width: 50, cellTemplate: '<button ng-hide=checkForNullId(row.entity.Id) id="deleteBtn" type="button" title="Trinti" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" ng-click="remove(row.entity)" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button> ' }
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the escape characters `\` as per the example.

Change the line,

```
{ field: 'Date', displayName: 'Register Date', cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd"' },
```

to

```
{ field: 'Date', displayName: 'Register Date', cellFilter: 'date:\'yyyy-MM-dd\'' },
```

**UPDATE**

From the database when you fetch the data, convert the `Date` with `moment` as below.

```
testData.Date = moment(testData.Date).format("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Nope, I have tried this one as first option, it doesn't work too. Any other suggestions? Maybe this one doesn't parse "/Date(1432617857710)/" and I have to do it some other way before formatting?

Comment: Thanks, I was working on old project, there I was doing in other way, I was parsing int, then making new Date(int) and after that creating string of toLocaleStringDate(), but I couldn't format it in a way I want. Momentum gave me that opportunity. :)